# Better Dragging for JQuery UI Sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using [jQuery UI's Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) to allow a user to sort a list. It has one detail that I am not happy with: When you move your mouse outside of the containing element, the drag does not work (see link). So if the user grabs the object all the way at the edge of the list (which they are likely to do since that's where the symbol is) then it does not feel like a smooth experience.

Anyone have a workaround for this?

Comment: Have you tested in your own page? I inspected the demo page and the reason the element can't get out of the container is because the container is an iframe, but the plugin does add "position: absolute; z-index: 1000" on the element while dragging

Comment: @EduardoWada I have. The issue is not the visibility of the element, but rather the fact that the order does not update. So you have to drag back into the div before you drop it again.

Comment: "Sorting" mean sorting among a group of items. If you drag something out of the list and do some crazy stuff with the mouse, of course it's not "sorting". If you want such behavior, use `draggable` and `droppable` widgets and implement your own logic...